# Flutter Error - Method 'setState' isn't defined for the type

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I need some help, I tried to make a code in flutter that moves the background image with AnimatedPositioned, but I found the following error:

The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'TerceiraRota'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'.

Can someone help me?
Tks!

````
class TerceiraRota extends StatelessWidget {
  double position=0;
  bool isFlipped=false;
  bool isStart=false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sad Shrek Adventures"),
      ),

      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedPositioned(
              top: -100,
              left: position,
              height: 660,
              child: Image.asset('imagens/swamp.jpg'),
              duration: Duration(microseconds: 200)),
          Positioned(
            top:470,
            left: 180,
            child: Container(
              height: 120.0,
              width: 120.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image:DecorationImage(
                image:AssetImage(
                  "imagens/shrektriste2.png"
                ),
              )
            ),
          ),
         ),
          Positioned(
            top:400,
            left:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-85,
            child: IconButton(
              icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  position -= 40;
                });
              })
          ),],
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `StatefulWidget`, in your code above you have extended `StatelessWidget`. Since the the `StatelessWidget` can not hold or modify the state of the widget it does not have the function `setState`, hence the name *Stateless*.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), you can find good examples there.

Answer (score 0):

You create a StatelessWidget.
StatelessWidget don't have state, so... setstate don't work.

If you want work with state, change your widget to a statefull widget.

Android Studio and VsCode make this change easy.
Put your mouse in Stateless word, click in the yellow lamp and choose "Convert to statefull widget".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `StatefulWidget` instead of `StatelessWidget` like this:

```
class TerceiraRota extends StatefulWidget {
  const TerceiraRota({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TerceiraRota> createState() => _TerceiraRotaState();
}

class _TerceiraRotaState extends State<TerceiraRota> {
  double position = 0;
  bool isFlipped = false;
  bool isStart = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Sad Shrek Adventures"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedPositioned(
            top: -100,
            left: position,
            height: 660,
            child: Image.asset('imagens/swamp.jpg'),
            duration: const Duration(microseconds: 200),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 470,
            left: 180,
            child: Container(
              height: 120.0,
              width: 120.0,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("imagens/shrektriste2.png"),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 400,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 85,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  position -= 40;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```